# How to use Color Maps in opengl? Shader interpolates weird stuff

Tags: java, opengl

I tried to display a texture using a 2D texture with index values and a 1D texture as a color map/ lookup table with the actual rgba colors.

I create the 1D texture with ths code (lwjgl):

```
public int loadColorMap(Color[] color) {

    ByteBuffer pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*256);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        byte red = color[i].getRedByte();
        byte green = color[i].getGreenByte();
        byte blue = color[i].getBlueByte();
        byte alpha = color[i].getAlphaByte();
        
        pixelBuffer.put(red);
        pixelBuffer.put(green);
        pixelBuffer.put(blue);
        pixelBuffer.put(alpha);
    }
    pixelBuffer.flip();

    int id = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_1D, id);
    GL11.glTexImage1D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, 256, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    return id;
}
```

The image itself I created with this code, using the red channel.

```
public int loadPixels(byte[] pixels) {

    ByteBuffer pixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pixels.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        byte pixel = pixels[i];
        pixelBuffer.put(pixel);
    }
    pixelBuffer.flip();

    int id = GL11.glGenTextures();
    GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RED, pow, pow, 0, GL11.GL_RED, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelBuffer);
    
    GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    GL11.glTexParameterf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL14.GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, -1);
    textures.add(id);

    return id;
}
```

This is my Shader code:

```
#version 400 core
in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform sampler1D colorSampler;

void main(void){

     float pos = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords).r;
     vec4 textureColour = texture(colorSampler, pos);

     out_Color = textureColour;
 }
```

But somehow i get some weird glitches. In the picture I moved the camera very close to the image. But instead of pixels you just see this kind of a noise effect. I also checked, if the color map is filled with all the same color, the texture is displaying this one color correct.

[image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMeTZ.jpg)

Comment: I guess the problem are the Mip Maps of the index texture... but how could i arrage tese correctly?

Comment: I don't think you can use anything else than nearest neighbor interpolation on a index texture anyway. Interpolating indices is not going to give you any reasonable effects. If you need linear interpolation, you have to implement that yourself in the shader. There might be better solutions for specific usecases, but for that we'd need to know why you are using indexed colors in first place.

Comment: Oh yes the nearest neighbour interpolation works. But it just works when i create my own mipmaps.It doesnt work with autogenerated mipmaps by glGenerateMipmap. I guess the glGenerateMipmap Function creates the MipMaps with some kind of average pixel method. so the indexes are just average values and doesnt match up with the color map anymore.

Is there a way to change this this mipmap creating algorythm of glGenerateMipmap?

Comment: `glGenerateMimaps` usually uses a 2x2 box filter. This can't be changed. If you need something else, then you need to generate them yourself.